# Windows screen idle turns off and directly on again

Tags: windows, display, power, idle

I have a very annoying issue with my monitors.
After the idle time specified in windows power management, my two displays turn off, but directly turn on again, preventing the monitors from entering screen saving mode completely and being turned on all the time.

This is really annoying as my computer is turned on for the most time of the day and this costs quite a lot of energy and probably wears down my monitors as well.

I checked `powercfg /sleepstudy` and the resulting log didn't even contain any events for "Screen off". However my guess is that they might not be logged because the duration of < 1 second is too short for it to log it.

I tried checking event log as well, but I could not find where such events might be logged.

EDIT 1:
Monitors are a Dell U2415 and LG 23' FHD monitor.
The log from `powercfg /energy` contained a warning about discord keeping my monitor active, but closing it (and checking the warning was gone) still did not solve the issue. I could post the full log but my locale is set to german (and MS just hast to make this log then german as well -.-') and I would have to strip it first a lot of private information.

Comment: What model are your monitors? What are your Windows sleep parameters in Power Options? Which Windows version? Post the result of [powercfg /energy](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/5148-create-power-efficiency-diagnostics-report-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: @harrymc I appended the information above